# guessing a random numer

Tags: javascript, html

i am learning javascript and i am trying to get a small number guessing "game", I guess you could call it.
A prompt shows up and asks you what your number will be. That input gets stored in a variable and then you can generate a random number.

I want to make it so if your guess is equal to the randomly generated number, the console logs a message.

HTML

```
<div class="random-wrapper">
    <div class="random-content">
        <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
        <p>Generate a random number between <span id="num1"></span>and <span id="num2"></span></p>
        <button id="generate" onclick="generateNumber();">Generate</button>
        <h2>Your random number is: <span id="result"></span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let guess = prompt("What is your guess?");
let num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
let num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

num1 = 1;
num2 = 10;
result.innerText = 0;

function generateNumber() {
    result.innerText = (Math.floor(Math.random() * num2) +1 );
    console.log(result);

    if (result == guess) {
        console.log("Your guess was correct!")
    };
}
```

Comment: The question is vague... what are console.logging, so what's the problem?

Comment: Well it is supposed to just print a message that your number you typed into the prompt is the same as the number u generated after typing in your prompt number.

Comment: `result == guess` compares a `string` (`guess`) to a DOM node (`result = document.getElementById("result")`). The simplest approach would be: `result.innerText == guess`.

Comment: Ahh right, because the input the user types is a string. I need to convert that to an actual number then, correct?

Comment: @AdrianB. I wouldn't, for any invalid input you'd end up with `NaN`. Ignoring the type coercion that's happening when you assign to `result.innerText`, the problem is that you're comparing the user input to a dom node. My recommendation would be to: 1) Store the random number, cast to string, in an extra variable. 2) Use that variable to assign to `result.innerText` 3) Compare the user input to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Was such a result necessary? In addition, I added the number of matches :) The line is Number of matches.

```js
let guess = prompt("What is your guess?");
let num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
let num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let result_matches = document.getElementById("matches");

num1 = 1;
num2 = 10;
result.innerText = 0;
number_matches = 0;

function generateNumber() {
    random_number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * num2) +1 );
    result.innerText = random_number;
    result_matches.innerText = number_matches;

    if (random_number == guess) {
        number_matches++;
        console.log(result.innerText + " --- " + "Your guess was correct!")
    } else {
        console.log(result.innerText);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="random-wrapper">
    <div class="random-content">
        <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
        <p>Generate a random number between <span id="num1"></span>and <span id="num2"></span></p>
        <button id="generate" onclick="generateNumber();">Generate</button>
        <h2>Your random number is: <span id="result"></span></h2>
        <h2>Number of matches: <span id="matches"></span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo

```js
const stringToIntegerNumber = (inputString) => {
  if(inputString == null) return;

  const number = Number.parseInt(inputString, 10);
  if(!Number.isInteger(number)) return;

  return number;
};

const promptIntegerStringTemplate = ({min, max} = {}) => {
  const existMinMax = min != null && max != null;
  
  const promptString = [
    'Enter a integer',
    ` [${min}-${max}]`,
    ': '
  ];

  return existMinMax ? promptString.join('') : promptString[0] + promptString[2];
}

const askIntegerNumber = ({min, max} = {}) => {
  let number, input;

  const promptString = promptIntegerStringTemplate({min, max});
  do {
    input = prompt(promptString);
    number = stringToIntegerNumber(input);
  } while(number == null);

  return number;
};

const isValidIntegerNumberInRange = (number, min, max) => {
  if(number == null || min == null || max == null
     || ( !Number.isInteger(number) )
     || ( !Number.isInteger(min) )
     || ( !Number.isInteger(max) )
    ) return;

  return number >= min && number <= max;
};

const generateRandomIntegerNumber = ({min = 0, max = 10} = {}) => {
  if( ( !Number.isInteger(min) )
     || ( !Number.isInteger(max) ) ) return;

  return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

const makeGuess = (min, max) => {
  let guess, validatedNumber;
  do {
    guess = askIntegerNumber({min, max});
    validatedNumber = isValidIntegerNumberInRange(guess, min, max) ? guess: null;
  } while(validatedNumber == null);

  return validatedNumber;
};

const updateNumber = (min, max) => {
  const num1 = document.querySelector('#num1');
  const num2 = document.querySelector('#num2');

  num1.textContent = min;
  num2.textContent = max;
};

const playGame = (min, max, randomInteger) => {
  const guess = makeGuess(min, max);
  if(guess === randomInteger)
    console.log(`Guess ${guess} is correct.`);
  else 
    console.log(`Guess ${guess} is incorrect.\nCorrect answer is ${randomInteger}`);
    
  //Visuals
  const result = document.querySelector('#result');
  result.textContent = randomInteger;
}

const domainControler = () => {
  const [min, max] = [1, 10];
  const randomInteger = generateRandomIntegerNumber({min, max});

  //Visuals
  updateNumber(min, max);

    //Play
  setTimeout(() => playGame(min, max, randomInteger), 5);
  
};

const setup = () => {
  const generate = document.querySelector('#generate');
  generate.addEventListener('click', domainControler);
};

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<div class="random-wrapper">
    <div class="random-content">
        <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
        <p>Generate a random number between <span id="num1"></span>and <span id="num2"></span></p>
        <button id="generate">Generate</button>
        <h2>Your random number is: <span id="result"></span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```